# Subsetting a large list and recombining into a dataframe

Tags: r

Say I have a list in R that has a lot of elements. They are structured like the example below (SYMBOLX 1999, SYMBOLX 2000, SYMBOLY 1999, SYMBOLY 2000, etc). I am trying to for each symbol put the years together (rbind) and then for the entire set of symbols put the newly combined years together into one dataframe (cbind).

Right now the code below seems pretty slow when I do it on even a list of 2600 elements. Could anyone suggest a more efficient way to accomplish this?

I made a hopefully reproducible example below (the actual values are not important, just random for now).

```
symbols <- c("SYMBOLX","SYMBOLY")

first <- structure(list(`_id` = "123182914914", symbol = "SYMBOLX", 
                        year = 1999, monthly = data.frame("COL2"=runif(10, -0.03, 0.03))),
                        .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "monthly"))
second <-structure(list(`_id` = "123182914915", symbol = "SYMBOLX", 
                        year = 2000, monthly = data.frame("COL2"=runif(10, -0.03, 0.03))),
                        .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "monthly"))

third <- structure(list(`_id` = "123182914916", symbol = "SYMBOLY", 
                        year = 1999, monthly = data.frame("COL2"=runif(10, -0.03, 0.03))),
                        .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "monthly"))
fourth <- structure(list(`_id` = "123182914917", symbol = "SYMBOLY", 
                         year = 2000, monthly = data.frame("COL2"=runif(10, -0.03, 0.03))),
                         .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "monthly"))

big_list <- list(first,second,third,fourth)

unique_years <- unique(unlist(lapply(big_list, '[[', 'year')))

all_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(symbols))
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  xts_data <- do.call("rbind", lapply(big_list[((length(unique_years)*(i-1))+1):(length(unique_years)*i)], '[[', 'monthly'))
  colnames(xts_data) <- symbols[i]
  all_data[[i]] <- xts_data
}
# create final output combined dataframe
master_data <- do.call("cbind", lapply(all_data, function(x) x))
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are doing, however, `with(do.call(rbind, lapply(big_list, as.data.frame)), cbind.data.frame(split(COL2, symbol)))` archieves the same result.

Comment: I got `x <- do.call("rbind", lapply(big_list, as.data.frame)); do.call("cbind", lapply(split(x, x$symbol), "[", "COL2"))`. :)

Comment: Those are both excellent. luke's also copies the column names. Learning a lot. Will edit in a bit to show what I am really doing (need to run each element (first, second, third, fourth) through a function to convert the format). Its from JSON to an xts, didnt want to complicate with that but looks like I should.